# to read excel data for a particular cell

Tags: python-3.x, xlrd

```
Overall Status                      
Number of Servers  Start time       End Time
                   1/12/2015 5:34AM 2/12/2015 07:30AM
Component1 Component2 Priority  Status      
1          5              Priority1         In Progress
```

for the above data in an excel sheet, I am using this code to extract data from the excel for all the columns together, but it is not giving any output -:

```
for i in range(sheet.nrows): row = sheet.row_values(i) for j in range(len(row)): if str(row[j]).strip()=="Revised/Estimated Completion Date Time": i+=2 print(sheet.cell_value(i,j)) if str(row[j]).strip()=="Planned Completion Date Time": i+=2 print(sheet.cell_value(i,j)) break
```

Comment: I'm no expert, but it may be helpful to list the library you are using to read in the sheet data.

Comment: Basically this code is working for the other rows ,but not working for any value in the second row

Comment: hi, It is working now, it was not working earlier because there was a space after "start time ". Is there a way I can make it ignore the before and after spaces??

Comment: You could use python's method `strip` for strings. Like this `row[j].strip() == "Start time"`, assuming that the index j of row will always return a string.

Comment: It throws the following error -:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#208>", line 4, in <module>
    if row[j].strip()=="Start":
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: Ah so looks like it doesn't always give you a string. So you probably want to convert it to a string first `str(row[j]).strip == "Start Time"`

Comment: Thanks a lot jphager2 it worked